# What is the difference between these fields in class

Tags: java, class, field

I am beginner Java programmer, learning OOP. I would like to know the names of the following fields.

```
private boolean probation;
private Car name;
private Sport sport;
```

I understand that the first field is a boolean (true/false), but I cannot seem to find out what the other fields are. Is there a explanations you can provide me to understand it better.

Comment: Some user-defined classes called `Car` and `Sport` respectively

Comment: `Car` and `Sport` are *classes;* you will find those elsewhere in the program, probably in separate files.

Comment: You should start with a good book on Java. You can also check **[Lesson: Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming, **all data has a type**. There are primitive types such as booleans, integers (int) strings (String), etc. However, you can also have more complex objects, such as an object to represent a Car or a Sport, etc.

Car and Sport are most likely defined in their own separate class files (Car.java and Sport.java) somewhere else in the source code. Classes are blueprints for objects. By defining a Car class, you are blueprinting how a Car object works, what properties it has, and what actions it can perform. In real life, all objects have a state (properties/attributes) and behaviors (actions that they can perform or have performed on them). The same is true of objects in code.

The first keyword private or public declares a variables scope within an object (which is outside the realm of this discussion) the next word boolean. Car, Sport defines the objects type, i.e. what type of object we are initializing, and the last word is the name of the variable used to store this object. So in your case you have a boolean variable called probation, a Car variable called name and a Sport variable called sport.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot seem to find out what the other fields are

They are just fields, nothing special to name with them.

You define a field with:

1. access modifier (`public`, `protected`, `private`, `default w/o modifier`) [optional];
2. non-access modifier (`static`, `volatile`, `final`, `transient`) [optional];
3. Type (either a primitive/value type or a class/reference type);
4. field variable identifier, that is the name of the variable.

Respectively:

```java
private boolean probation; //boolean field (field of a type boolean)
private Car name; //Car field (field of a type Car)
private Sport sport; //Sport field (field of a type Sport)
```